# Where to find detailed information about space mission like Voyager or Galileo

Tags: gravity-assist, reference-request, scientific-data

Is there any place aside from [NASA-JPL](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/missions/galileo) web page, where there is only some general information about the missions, where one can find more in-depth detailed values?

For instance, I am looking for the values concerning the gravity-assist maneuvers that Galileo and Voyager did, like incoming-outgoing speeds, turning angle, periapsis radius, eccentricity, etc. 
I can find some of the values in papers and other web pages, but that is not ideal as some of the values are just approximations and some don't even refer the source.

Is there any official place where real detailed values of missions can be found?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Design & Performance Summary Series](https://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/DPSummary/summary.html), also [Simulation and Study of Gravity Assist Maneuvers](https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1440099/FULLTEXT01.pdf), and [A historical review of the theory of gravity‐assists in the pre‐spaceflight era](http://mtc-m21c.sid.inpe.br/col/sid.inpe.br/mtc-m21c/2020/07.22.11.13/doc/Negri-Prado2020_Article_AHistoricalReviewOfTheTheoryOf.pdf) ?

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome thanks for the proposals! They are like the others, however. Some values here and there but that's it. I assumed that extensive reports presenting the performance and values of the mission were published...

Comment: For Voyager 1, Horizons has "A patched conic mission-design type trajectory in which the conics were constructed to approximately match specific events, such as satellite encounters, providing a rough accuracy". https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&OBJ_DATA=YES&MAKE_EPHEM=NO&COMMAND=-31 Note that improvements to that trajectory data were made just last month.

Comment: FWIW, I have scripts that can make interactive 3D trajectory plots. See https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/49823/16685